# jQuery, Prepend data strips html tags, and output gets messed up

Tags: html, jquery

I have below code to retrieve some text from a php document:

```
$.get("server/test.php", function(data){
    $('#thumbdest').prepend(data);
    // $('#thumbdest').html(data);
});
```

The commented line returns everything as expected, but the `prepend` data does not. It seems to strip HTML tags when inserted. I can't use the commented line because I have to insert multiple items after each other. `$('#thumbdest').html(data);` replaces everything in the `thumbdest` div as expected.

Below is the HTML I should get when using `prepend`

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="#modal" class="thumbnail tableimg"  role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">           
            <img src="assets/img/huvudbilder/thumbs/img.png" class="tableimg" alt="">
        </a>
    </td>
    <td>Test1</td>
    <td>Test2</td>                
</tr>
```

This is what I actually get from using `prepend`

```
<a href="#modal" class="thumbnail tableimg"  role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">
    <img src="assets/img/huvudbilder/thumbs/img.png" class="tableimg" alt="">
</a>
Test1
Test2
```

Which in turn screws up the whole table. All the table elements disappear, why is that?

EDIT:
When testing `alert(data)` after the prepend I get below:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="#editImage_1222866094" class="thumbnail tableimg"  role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">

            <img src="assets/img/huvudbilder/thumbs/favicon32.png" class="tableimg" alt="">
        </a>
    </td>
    <td>Test1</td>
    <td>Test2</td>                     
</tr>
```

Structure of the `#thumbdest`:

```
        <table class="table table-hover">
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Namn</th>
                    <th>Tid</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="thumbdest"></tbody>
            <tbody>
                <?php getImageList($conn); ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Can you please edit your post to include what is returned in the `data` variable.

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/), prepend is not supposed to escape html.

Comment: Where is #thumbdest in your code, i can't find it in your html

Comment: What is the html in the div at the outset?

Comment: #thumbdest is in a tbody `<tbody id="thumbdest"></tbody>`

Comment: @AlbinN Is `tbody` child of a table element?

Comment: Please post the markup of your table.

Comment: @undefined Just posted it :)

Comment: Seems to be working here: http://jsfiddle.net/PbLer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Script Test</title>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    // example

        $(function() {
            $('.button').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var $mytext = "<a href=\"#\">Test</a>";
                    $("#key").prepend($mytext);

                });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <a href="" class="button">Test</a>
    <div id="key"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here, `prepend()` is working as it is supposed to, not to strip tags.

**What you need to do** is to place the `<tbody>` inside the `<div id="thumbdest">` and then change your following script line from `$('#thumbdest').prepend(data);` to `$('#thumbdest tbody').prepend(data);`

Source: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/prepend-stripping-out-html-table-tags